# Using Jsoup to scrape for urls from google search results

Tags: java, web-scraping, jsoup

I trying to make a method that takes the name of a location and returns the URL for the weather.com page for that location. I am trying to get the URL of the first search result but I am struggling.

```
    {

        String temp = loc.replace(" ","+"); //insert the desired location into a google search
        String input = "https://www.google.com/search?q="+temp+"+site%3Aweather.com%2Fweather%2Ftoday&rlz=1C1VDKB_enUS946US946&ei=RXacYvTuDs_SuvQPiOagkA8&ved=0ahUKEwi0pajd_pX4AhVPqY4IHQgzCPIQ4dUDCA4&uact=5&oq="+temp+"+site%3Aweather.com%2Fweather%2Ftoday&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EANKBAhBGABKBAhGGABQAFiFEWC-EmgAcAB4AIABUIgB7gaSAQIxM5gBAKABAcABAQ&sclient=gws-wiz";
        try{
            doc = Jsoup.connect(input).get();
            Elements e = doc.select("div.yuRBf");
            Element link = e.select("a").first();
            System.out.println(link.attr("href")); //I thought this would return the url
            
            System.out.println("done");
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Are these the correct jsoup methods to use to extract a URL?

Answer (score 0):

I think I may have fixed the issue. I used `Elements resultLinks = doc.select("a[href]");` to select all the links from the search. Then a for each loop that returns the first URL containing "weather.com".

New Code:

```
 doc = Jsoup.connect(input).get();
            Elements resultLinks = doc.select("a[href]");
            for (Element e: resultLinks)
            {
                if(e.attr("href").indexOf("https://weather.com/weather/today")!=-1)
                {
                    url = e.attr("href");
                    System.out.println(url);
                    break;
                }
            }
```